# Asp.net Bundling/minification return old files after minification

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, web-optimization

We are using bundling and minification with asp.net MVC with web optimization 1.1.0.0. Previously it was working fine however we are facing issue now.

We have changed one of the js file and it is not reflecting in the minification, it taking older js file for minification. It also update the has once file get changed.

Whenever we add "BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true" it minification done with older js file and render it on UI.
and when we "BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false" it render updated JS file on UI.

Anyone has suggestion ?

Comment: are you checking it on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was, i had the .min.js file of changed .js at the same location.

i changed .js but havent changed .min.js

If you have .min.js file the bundling/minification will pick up the .min file from folder.

So please take care when you changes .js and you have .min.js @ same location.